# chmod - file permission on executable

Tags: python, permissions, executable, chmod

I have to change file permissions on an executable file, using `os.chmod`.
I have this executable and I want to change its permissions so that it can write nowhere, only reading and executing.
How can I do that?

Thanks,
rubik

Comment: `chmod` doesn't do that. What you need is to run the process in a sandbox .

Comment: [Similar question posted on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24469/chmod-change-permissions-on-a-file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions you can set on a file with `chmod` affect who can read from/write to/execute that file, not what privileges the process created by running that file has.

On Unix you could get some form of protection by playing with the file owner and the sticky bit, and having appropriate permissions on your filesystem, but that's not easy to get right and doesn't work on Windows (no sticky bit there).

Comment: Thank you, but I can't see what sticky bit can do for me. I've read the Wikipedia article about that.

Comment: If you set the owner of an executable to, for example, `nobody` and put a sticky bit on it, when you run that executable the process will start _as if_ it had been launched by the `nobody` user (regardless of what user actually started it). If `nobody` has no write access to the files/directories you care about, that process won't be able to mess with them.

Answer (score 1):

> I have this executable and I want to change its permissions so that it can write nowhere, only reading and executing

That's not how `chmod` works - it sets permissions on the file itself, it can't restrict what an executable can write to.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround used by some Linux or Unixes to forbid an executable to write something is to make that executable setuid to a user which has no permission (which nearly "don't exist"), such as the `nobody` user (e.g. in Debian or Ubuntu). Be careful and read more about [seteuid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/seteuid) & [setreuid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setreuid) & [capabilities](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) & [credentials](http://linux.die.net/man/7/credentials) (and I don't know precisely if all these syscalls have a pythonic interface).